# Чем компилировать модули расширений на Cython под Windows 7 x64?

Tags: python, x86-64

Имеются сборки СPython и Суthon под архитектуру amd64 (взяты отсюда: [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) ). В доках по `Cython` говорится, что компилировать расширения желательно той же версией компилятора, которой собран `CPython`. Проблема в отсутствии 64-битного компилятора в VC++ `Express` - нагуглил, что он есть в `Windows SDK`. Но и после установки `Windows SDK` скрипт `setup.py` выдает, что файл `vcvarsall.bat` не найден.

Comment: vcvarsall.bat не найден на диске или в директориях, указанных в переменной %path% ?

Comment: Возможно это поможет: [Python проблема с vcvarsall.bat](http://xn--80afqpaigicolm.xn--p1ai/python/python-problema-s-vcvarsallbat-reshenie/)

Comment: В принципе, нагуглил ответ на свой вопрос http://lib.custis.ru/index.php?title=Python_x64_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_Windows_7&useskin=cleanmonobook. Но теперь при выполнении \distutils\msvc9compiler.py на 299 строчке вылетает ошибка "ValueError: [u'path, u'include', u'lib']. Версия Python - 2.7.3

Comment: всё получилось! Ошибка была вызвана тем, что в из оффлайновой сборки Windows SDK ставится версия 7.0, а с помощью online installer - 7.1